# List of Nat of Fixed Size and Element Bounds

Tags: scala, shapeless

Using `shapeless`, I'm trying to define a function:

```
import shapeless._
import ops.nat._
import nat._

def threeNatsLessThan3[N <: Nat](xs: Sized[List[N], N])
   (implicit ev: LTEq[N, _3]) = ???
```

where it will only compile if the input `xs` is a `List` (of sized 3) of `Nat` where each element is <= 3.

But that fails to compile:

```
scala> threeNatsLessThan3[_3](List(_1,_2,_3))
<console>:22: error: type mismatch;
 found   : List[shapeless.Succ[_ >: shapeless.Succ[shapeless.Succ[shapeless._0]] with shapeless.Succ[shapeless._0] with shapeless._0 <: Serializable with shapeless.Nat]]
 required: shapeless.Sized[List[shapeless.nat._3],shapeless.nat._3]
    (which expands to)  shapeless.Sized[List[shapeless.Succ[shapeless.Succ[shapeless.Succ[shapeless._0]]]],shapeless.Succ[shapeless.Succ[shapeless.Succ[shapeless._0]]]]a>
       twoNatsFirstLtEqSecond[_3](List(_1,_2,_3))
                                      ^
```

How can I implement the above function correctly?

Also I would appreciate a solution using an HList too, where the `HList` consists only of `Nat` elements (if possible).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're typing as the signature is a `List` of size `N` which contains only elements of type `N`. To whit, `Sized[List[N], N]` denotes one of the following: `List(_1)`, `List(_2, _2)`, or finally `List(_3, _3, _3)`, taking into consideration your type level constraint. That's almost what you want and explains the error the compiler is giving you:

```
required: shapeless.Sized[List[shapeless.nat._3],shapeless.nat._3]
```

To begin breaking down what you want to accomplish we need to note that you can't have a `List[Nat]` and also preserve the individual types. The abstractness of `Nat` would obscure them. So if you want to do things at compile time, you're going to have three choices: work with an `HList`, choose to fix the type of `Nat` within the list so that you have `List[N]` or choose to fix the size of the `List[Nat]` with `Sized`.

If you want to say that the `List` has size less than 3, then

```
def lessThanThree[N <: Nat](sz: Sized[List[Nat], N])(implicit ev: LTEq[N, _3]) = sz
```

If you want to say that the `List` has a `Nat` of less than three, again with a fixed `N` within the `List`:

```
def lessThanThree[N <: Nat, M <: Nat](sz: Sized[List[N], M])(implicit ev: LTEq[N, _3]) = sz
```

If you're looking to perhaps work with a `Poly` where you could define an `at` for any `Nat` such that it preserves the `LTEq` constraint, you'll need to understand that `Sized` does make working with `map` conform closer to the standard package `map` found on most collections, i.e. it requires a `CanBuildFrom`. That combined with the erasure of the individual `Nat` in `List` means that you'll have a lot of difficulty coming up with a solution which gives you the type of flexibility you're looking for.

If you were to work with an `HList`, you could do the following:

```
 object LT3Identity extends Poly{
   implicit def only[N <: Nat](implicit ev: LTEq[N, _3]) = at[N]{ i => i}
 }

 def lt3[L <: HList, M <: Nat](ls: L)(implicit lg: Length.Aux[L, M], lt: LTEq[M, _3]) = ls.map(LT3Identity)
```

which does both constrain your size of the `Hlist` to less than 3 while also only allowing `HList` that contain `Nat` of less than or equal to 3.

Comment: Taking your second definition of `lessThanThree`, why does the following not compile: `lessThanThree[_2, _2](List(_2, _2))`?

Comment: @KevinMeredith because you need to surround it with a `Sized`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39876940/building-fixed-size-list-of-nat-n demonstrates my question - thanks.

Comment: @KevinMeredith unfortunately I haven't worked with Sized when it hasn't already existed... you might want to ask in the Shapeless Gitter channel, linking your question there.