# Building Fixed Size List of Nat N

Tags: scala, shapeless

I tried to define a function that, given a `N <: Nat` type parameter, builds a List with exactly 3 `N`'s.

```
import shapeless._
import shapeless.nat._

scala> def natNOfSize3[N <: Nat](n: Nat): Sized[List[N], _3] = 
     Sized[List, _3](List(n, n, n))
<console>:17: error: wrong number of type parameters for overloaded method value apply with alternatives:
  [CC[_]]()(implicit cbf: scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom[Nothing,Nothing,CC[Nothing]], implicit ev: shapeless.AdditiveCollection[CC[Nothing]])shapeless.Sized[CC[Nothing],shapeless._0] <and>
  [CC[_]]=> shapeless.SizedBuilder[CC]

       def natNOfSize3[N <: Nat](n: Nat): Sized[List[N], _3] = Sized[List, _3](List(n, n, n))             ^
```

But I don't understand why it failed.

Comment: like Travis said, your arguments to Sized(...) are incorrect, you are passing a collection instead of just the elements.
Note: 
Sized.apply returns a SizedBuilder https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/shapeless/sized.scala
SizedBuilder.apply takes the elementshttps://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/b73453bab27e73b6aa1206805e73ec583852309d/project/Boilerplate.scala

Compiler magic makes them look like a single function call.

Comment: Interesting - https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/b73453bab27e73b6aa1206805e73ec583852309d/project/Boilerplate.scala#L428, Marcus. Any blog posts that you can please recommend that comment on this `Boilerplate` class?

Comment: No blog posts that I know of however the comment at https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/b73453bab27e73b6aa1206805e73ec583852309d/project/Boilerplate.scala#L115 may be explanation enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One issue is that your `n` is typed as `Nat`, not `N`—I assume that's just a typo. Once you've fixed that, you can write the method like this:

```
import shapeless._, nat._

def natNOfSize3[N <: Nat](n: N): Sized[List[N], _3] = Sized[List](n, n, n)
```

Note that `Sized.apply` takes a single type parameter of kind `* -> *`, and instead of providing a collection, you provide the elements.

If you really want to pass in a collection, you could use `wrap`:

```
def natNOfSize3[N <: Nat](n: N): Sized[List[N], _3] = Sized.wrap(List(n, n, n))
```

But then the compiler isn't going to be able to help you if you've lied about the number of elements.

Comment: How do you know that its kind is `* -> *` from https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/b73453bab27e73b6aa1206805e73ec583852309d/core/src/main/scala/shapeless/sized.scala#L29, Travis?

Comment: @KevinMeredith You need to look at [the `apply`](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/b73453bab27e73b6aa1206805e73ec583852309d/core/src/main/scala/shapeless/sized.scala#L189) in the companion object.